# Escape " between to Strings

Tags: java, regex, replace, escaping

I'm getting an Json and then using Gson to deserialize it in an object where value is a String not an object.. so i'm trying to put that object into a String variable - not deserialized

I want to do something like this:

`"{value" : {"id":"2"}}` -> `{"value" : "{\"id\":\"2\"}"}`

I replaced the `"value" : {` with `"value" : "{` like this:

```
result = result.replace("\"value\" : {", "\"value\" : \"{");
```

and then I replaced the }} like this:

```
result = result.replace("}}", "}\"}");
```

And my result was (after replacing everything):

```
{"value" : "{"id":"2","name":"game2"}"}
```

the only problem now: i also want to replace the `"` with `\"` but only inside the `"{` ... `}"` I can't figure that out.

EDIT:

Incoming Json:

```
{"path" : "/gdi/games/2", "key" : "detail", "value" : {"id":"2","name":"game2"}}, 
{"path" : "/gdi/games/4", "key" : "detail", "value" : {"id":"4","name":"game4"}}, 
{"path" : "/gdi/games/6", "key" : "detail", "value" : {"id":"6","name":"game6"}}
```

The problem: value: could be anything (text) so I only want to store everything which cames between { } in my Object which become deserialized in an object that looks like:

```
String path;
String key;
String value;
```

To achieve this I have to escape the object (which is in "value") like it is String - After escaping that Gson can deserialize it for me.

Json needed:

```
{"path" : "/gdi/games/2", "key" : "detail", "value" : "{\"id\":\"2\",\"\name\":\"game2\"}"}, 
{"path" : "/gdi/games/4", "key" : "detail", "value" : "{\"id\":\"4\",\"\name\":\"game4\"}"}, 
{"path" : "/gdi/games/6", "key" : "detail", "value" : "{\"id\":\"6\",\"\name\":\"game6\"}"}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should start off by using a JSON API rather than trying to manipulate something *like* JSON with string operations. What's the context here?

Comment: Where are you doing that? In a JSP? Are you using Struts?

Comment: I'm getting an Json and then using Gson to serialize it in an object where value is a String not an object.. so i'm trying to put that object into a String variable - not serialized

Comment: Added the context @JonSkeet

Comment: What you're trying to do is serialize the value, then serialize an object containing the serialized value. So why not just do that?

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but  i am 87 percent sure that you can do it a better way. any way to answer your question i suggest the use of stack. there is a known algorithm of counting open parenthesis, you should use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
input = input.replaceAll("(?=\"[^{}]*\\})", "\\\\");
```

It uses a look ahead to assert that the next curly bracket found after a double quote is a *right* curly - meaning the double quote must be *within* a pair of curly brackets.

The replacement term is a literal backslash - four backslashes needed due to double-escape: one for java string literal, one for regex escape.

---

Here's some test code using your sample input an producing your expected output:

```
String input = 
    "{\"path\" : \"/gdi/games/2\", \"key\" : \"detail\", \"value\" : {\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"game2\"}}," +
    "{\"path\" : \"/gdi/games/4\", \"key\" : \"detail\", \"value\" : {\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"game4\"}}," +
    "{\"path\" : \"/gdi/games/6\", \"key\" : \"detail\", \"value\" : {\"id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"game6\"}}";
input = input.replaceAll("(?=\"[^{}]*\\})", "\\\\");
System.out.println(input);
```

Output:

```
{"path" : "/gdi/games/2", "key" : "detail", "value" : {\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"game2\"}},
{"path" : "/gdi/games/4", "key" : "detail", "value" : {\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"game4\"}},
{"path" : "/gdi/games/6", "key" : "detail", "value" : {\"id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"game6\"}}
```

Comment: That really did the trick. Thanks! Using it like that:
result = result.replace("\"value\" : {", "\"value\" : \"{");
result = result.replaceAll("(?=\"[^{}]*\\})", "\\\\");
result = result.replace("}}", "}\"}");

To get my needed Json! Thanks!

Comment: No worries. It's amazing what you can do with the right regex!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jackson` library to map data to a class. 
http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial

For printing backslashes - example

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a="{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"game2\"}";
        System.out.println("Before - "+a);
        System.out.println("After - "+a.replace("\"", "\\\""));
    }
```

output -

```
Before - {"id":"2","name":"game2"}
After - {\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"game2\"}
```

Comment: thats all good i know how to replace " with \" but my problem is that I only want to do that between "value" : { ... }

Answer (score -1):

you just need to add double \ if you want to add "\"
for example: System.out.println("\\"");
print this statement you will get : \"
String abc: "\\"";

Comment: that is not the issue . "only inside {..} " is the issue

Comment: to be more specific only inside: "\"value\" : {"

Comment: @KaranDani You may want to review the formatting guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting